# How to merge values of two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, merge

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array(
    array("id" => 132),
    array("id" => 131),
    array("id" => 129),
    array("id" => 128)
)

$b = array(
    array("id" => 129, "attachment_id" => 111),
    array("id" => 129, "attachment_id" => 112),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 113),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 114),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 115)
)
```

I need to make one array from those two. `id` key must be unique so it can't be repeated. Problem is that: I need to make new element in that new array called `attachments` that's array and contains values of `attachment_id` for that `id`. You see, there may be more that one `attachment_id` for `id`.

Its hard to explain, but I hope that you'll understand! Thanks in advice.

**Edit:**

Here is desired outcome:

```
$c = array(
    array("id" => 132, 'attachments' => array(113, 114, 115)),
    array("id" => 131, 'attachments' => array()),
    array("id" => 129, 'attachments' => array(111, 112)),
    array("id" => 128, 'attachments' => array())
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$a = array(
    array("id" => 132),
    array("id" => 131),
    array("id" => 129),
    array("id" => 128)
);

$b = array(
    array("id" => 129, "attachment_id" => 111),
    array("id" => 129, "attachment_id" => 112),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 113),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 114),
    array("id" => 132, "attachment_id" => 115)
);

$c = array();

foreach ($a as $idEntry) {
    $tmp = array(
        'id' => $idEntry['id'],
        'attachments' => array()
    );

    foreach ($b as $bIdx => $attachmentEntry) {
        if ($attachmentEntry['id'] == $idEntry['id']) {
            $tmp['attachments'][] = $attachmentEntry['attachment_id'];
            unset($b[$bIdx]);
        }
    }

    $c[] = $tmp;
}

print_r($c);
```

Comment: @daGrevis "almost" because of?? :)

Comment: Please look at my question's edits. Outcome isn't like I want it to be. ;(

Comment: @daGrevis, maybe you missed it but my answer gives the result you want.

Comment: Fixed myself. `$attachmentEntry['id']` must be `$attachmentEntry['attachment_id']`.

Comment: Is there any painless way to also add other elements of `$a` to `$c`? http://pastie.org/2242240

Comment: @daGrevis Yes, just add the values you want where `$tmp` is created.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
# Temporary array
$c = array();

# Loop through all attachments and index them by id
foreach($b as $row) {
    if(!isset($c[$row['id']])) {
        $c[$row['id']] = array();
    }
    $c[$row['id']][] = $row['attachment_id'];
}

# Loop through ids and add attachments where available
foreach($a as &$row) {
    $row['attachments'] = isset($c[$row['id']]) ? $c[$row['id']] : array()
} unset($row);
```

Output:

```
array(
    array("id" => 132, "attachments" => array(113, 114, 115)),
    array("id" => 131, "attachments" => array()),
    array("id" => 129, "attachments" => array(111, 112)),
    array("id" => 128, "attachments" => array())
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Index your arrays by 'id' and then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php